# URL Rewrite - Does order of directories matter to search engines?

Tags: url-rewriting, subdirectory

So a pretty straight forward question here. Should the directory structure created from url parameters such as: /color-brown/shape-square/material-wood/ remain consistent? Does it matter if you also link to /shape-square/material-wood/color-brown/and it provides the same results? Will a search engine read this as a completely different page?

Thanks for your time. I tried finding an answer to this but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the order of the "directories" matters. Google can't distinguish between a parameter-generated rewrite and "real" subdirectories, so it would see any different ordering of parameters as completely separate pages, and consider them duplicate content.

Comment: I assumed as much. Thank you.